# Checkbox with Confirmation and Stay with Original Checkbox Value if Cancel

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

There is a checkbox value. When change the checkbox value I asked from user "Do you want to SHOW this item on website?" or "Do you want to HIDDEN this item on website?"

It is works fine. But the problem is **cancel** option. If user tick the check box confirm box will appear that "Do you want to SHOW this item on website?". But even user select cancel it will marked as selected. Even I use `document.getElementsByName("product").checked = false;` to make untick again, it is not worked.

**JS Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/9mvrfuyd/7/

**Note : Please No jQuery Solution. Only pure JavaScript.**

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product" onchange="change_property_status(this.checked);">Option 1
```

JavaScript

```
function change_property_status(status){
  if(status){
    status = 1;
    var con_message = confirm("Do you want to SHOW this item on website?");
    if(!con_message){
      document.getElementsByName("product").checked = false;
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    status = 0;
    var con_message = confirm("Do you want to HIDDEN this item on website?");
    if(!con_message){
      document.getElementsByName("product").checked = true;
      return false;
    }
  }

 }
```

**Update : I have not used id attribute for checkbox but I used `getElementsByName`. So it is not a problem.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just missing `[0]` in `getElementsByName()`

```
document.getElementsByName("product")[0].checked = true;
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/to7k9ca9/)

> The `getElementsByName()` method returns a collection of all elements in
>   the document with the specified name (the value of the name
>   attribute), as a NodeList object.
>
> The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be
>   accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think `getElementsByName` return list a of element so you need to add index to it.
`document.getElementsByName("product")[0].checked = false;`

Comment: that live demo still missing `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Add the id="product" inside the input tag.

Comment: he use getElementsByName

Comment: oh! just noted. I'll check it again.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will helpful to you

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="product" name="product" onchange="change_property_status(this.checked);">Option 1
```

Javascript

```
function change_property_status(status){
  if(status){
    status = 1;
    var con_message = confirm("Do you want to SHOW this item on website?");

    if(con_message == false){
        document.getElementById("product").checked = false;
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    status = 0;
    var con_message = confirm("Do you want to HIDDEN this item on website?");
    if(con_message == false){
      document.getElementById("product").checked = true;
      return false;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Not working............... I don't think that there is problem using `getElementByName` instead of `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using JQuery.

```
$('element selector here').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  # further logic
```

})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).